# WF Access the workflow instance variables from load and unload

Tags: workflow-foundation

In workflowRuntime_WorkflowUnloaded and Loaded etc.. the only thing I can get which is pretty useless is the workflowinstanceId. I want to be able to access some DPs that are on the root activity, whenever I do a GetWorkFlowDefintion() and cast to root activity, all the property that I've passed in are all null..

Answer (score 1):

You have to use the TrackingServices to get more than just the basic info. See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms735887(VS.85).aspx

We use the default sqlTrackingService, host the workflow in a windows service, it is exposed using wcf and it is a state machine workflow.

Here is how we used it in one case:

```
SqlTrackingWorkflowInstance instance = null;
//wfServiceHost is an instance of WorkflowServiceHost
WorkflowRuntimeBehavior workflowRuntimeBehaviour = wfServiceHost.Description.Behaviors.Find<WorkflowRuntimeBehavior>();
WorkflowRuntime wfRuntime = workflowRuntimeBehaviour.WorkflowRuntime;

if (wfRuntime != null)
{
        SqlTrackingService trackingService = (SqlTrackingService)wfRuntime.GetService(typeof(SqlTrackingService));
        SqlTrackingQuery sqlTrackingQuery = new SqlTrackingQuery(trackingService.ConnectionString);

         sqlTrackingQuery.TryGetWorkflow(instanceId, out instance);
}
```

Comment: +1 for using the existing trackingService connection reference and  passing that to the SqlTrackingQuery ctor.

Answer (score 0):

OK, I have managed to use the above to retrieve business-data (i.e. an ID) which lives inside the workflow, but I had to add a

```
this.TrackData("name", myObject)
```

into my initial activity inside the workflow.

At that point, I was able to get the ID from `myObject` (`Job`) by the following code. Yippee!

```
foreach (UserTrackingRecord userTrackingRecord in
    sqlTrackingWorkflowInstance.UserEvents)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Key : {0}  Data : {1}",
        userTrackingRecord.UserDataKey,
        userTrackingRecord.UserData.ToString());
    if (userTrackingRecord.UserDataKey == "Job")
    {
        OrderRequest request = userTrackingRecord.UserData as OrderRequest;
        if (request != null)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("\nJob ID: {0}", request.JobID);
        }
    }
}
```